# In Haskell, how do you check whether a string is a substring of another?

Tags: string, haskell

I'm using Data.Text and all I could find are `find`, which only takes a Char as predicate, and `breakOn`, which would allow me to do what I want but seems overkill. Surely there must be a better way?

I'd be interested in the answer to the same question with other string libraries as well (String, ByteString, etc.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found it, the answer is [`isInfixOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:isInfixOf).

Comment: Just wrote that up as [an SO Documentation example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/3406/data-text/24312/checking-if-one-text-is-a-substring-of-another#t=201610072318129590912) :)